# Custom MaterialSearchView Displayed Under Toolbar in a Fragment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I'm using a custom MaterialSearchview, and my project is as the following :

Layouts:

```
MainLayout
FragmentSection Layout
```

Codes :

```
MainActivity 
SectionFragment
```

In the MainActivity there's a Drawer library, i have 6 sections, only one of those fragments has a Search icon, so here's my problem .

In main layout i have a toolbar and a fragment :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
tools:context="com.abohani.ramadantime.MainActivity">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap"
    android:minHeight="@dimen/abc_action_bar_default_height_material"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />




<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

As you can see, the fragment is under the toolbar, so when the transaction is made, the Search shows under the toolbar, why ?

because i'm adding the searchview in my fragment layout, and i'm repalcing the MainLayout @id/fragment with my fragment layout, and that fragment view is under toolbar => Searchview shows under .

What do i need ? i'd like a help to fix this, a different logic on it ?

Here's my fragment layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/rel"
android:orientation="vertical">

<com.lapism.searchview.SearchView
    android:id="@+id/searchView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    />

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/fav_rv"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/no_match"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<include
    android:id="@+id/loading_layout"
    layout="@layout/loading_progress"/>



</RelativeLayout>
```